# Wordpress: Header not showing on pages and scrollspy error

Tags: javascript, wordpress

so I have a problem with page header which is not showing at all on a page. every page has `get_header()` function. also on some pages there is an error :

> TypeError: jQuery(...).scrollspy is not a function

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added/enqueued Bootstrap JS properly. The error indicates you didn't add Bootstrap Javascript files correctly. Please provide the URL.

Comment: Ipscontract.ge This is the url